# Evans PDE chapter 2 problem 4

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Problem is

> Give a direct proof that if $u \in C^{2}(U) \cap C(\overline{U})$ is harmonic within a bounded open set $U$, then
>   $\max_{\overline{U}} u =\max_{\partial U} u$.

What I think is that;

> Let $u^{\epsilon} = u+ \epsilon |x|^{2}$, where $\epsilon >0 $. Then $\bigtriangleup u^{\epsilon} = \bigtriangleup u + 2\epsilon |x| = 2\epsilon |x| \geq 0$ since $u$ is harmonic. Equality holds if $x=0$.  Suppose $x_{0} \in U$ is maximum point of $u^{\epsilon}(\overline{U})$. Then $\bigtriangleup u^{\epsilon}(x_0) = 2 \epsilon |x_0| \leq 0$.

I want to show that $x_0 \neq 0$, so this is contradiction, but I don't know how to do that. Could anyone have an idea?

Comment: You also have $\Delta u^\epsilon = 2\epsilon$.

Comment: @Vintarel You definitely right! I had a mistakes on laplacian |x|^2. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $u_{\varepsilon} = u + \varepsilon |x|^2, \forall \varepsilon > 0$. Then $\Delta u_{\varepsilon} = 2 \epsilon > 0$ since $u$ is harmonic. If $u_{\varepsilon}$ attained a local maximum at an interior point then $\Delta u \le 0$. Thus, $u_{\varepsilon}$ attains its maximum on the boundary and has no maximum at an interior point. If $|x| \le r, \forall x \in U$, it follow that
$$
\sup_U u \le \sup_U u_{\varepsilon} \le \sup_{\partial U} u_{\varepsilon} \le \sup_{\partial U} (u + \varepsilon r^2) .
$$ 
Let $\varepsilon \to 0$ we get $\sup_U u \le \sup_{\partial U} u$ and $\max_{\partial U} = \max_{\bar{U}} u$.

Comment: If $u_{\epsilon}=u+\epsilon \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$
then isn't $\Delta u_{\epsilon}=\Delta u +2n\epsilon$? What am I missing

Answer (score -1):

If the maximum is attained inside the domain, at point $x_0$, then the Hessian $H$ of $u$ at $x_0$ is symmetric definite negative. You first have that
$$Tr(H) = \Delta u$$
and because H is definite negative,
$$Tr(H) < 0$$
This implies a contradiction with $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I cannot think about hessian!

Comment: Actually that's not a direct proof, is it? By the way, the mean value property directly implies that no maximum won't be attained in the interior.

Comment: Maxima can be attained at points where the Hessian is only negative *semi*definite, so this argument is not correct.